# How to open the file using FileDialog and display the path into textbox in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

How to open the file using FileDialog and display the path into textbox in asp.net mvc?

Comment: Remember that the whole "selecting a file" part is being done client-side, so you might need to use JavaScript if you need to manipulate that data before sending it to the server.

Answer (score 1):

use  `<input type="file" name="imageFile" />`

on the controller for your POST method include this `HttpPostedFileBase imageFile`

```
if (imageFile != null && imageFile.ContentLength > 0)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(imageFile.FileName);
    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(imageFile.FileName);
}
```